# No accepted answer left behind

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

> Small curvature 'twixt solid and liquid.
> A number in a poolside ballroom.
> An old-fashioned style of name.

> An undead islander.
> Constricted perspective.
> For kids not to be scared.
> A battle of strength.

What's going on here?

Hint:

> This is my attempt at a Hugh Meyers style riddle.

Comment: Is it worth links in your hint, for those not as familiar with the site regulars? Also, I don't know if you need to update/change the tags?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Small curvature 'twixt solid and liquid.

> bight

> A number in a poolside ballroom.

> eight (the most famous number to be found where balls are stored near a pool hall)

> An old-fashioned style of name.

> hight

---

> An undead islander.

> Wight wight

> Constricted perspective.

> tight sight

> For kids not to be scared.

> night light

> A battle of strength.

> might fight

---

> No accepted answer left behind

> Every right answer is not left but right!

Comment: Awesome! Almost everything is exactly what I intended, but you've overcomplicated the first three lines a bit: each of those is supposed to clue just one five-letter word, while the later lines clue two words each. Btw, what about the title?

Comment: Hint for line 2: two of the words don't have the meanings that you're thinking of :-)

Comment: Perfect, now you got everything. (The title could almost work as a cryptic clue: "the accepted answer will be not left *behind*".)